# How to write .properties file from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, properties

Hi 
   i new to java i stuck here please help me...
   my problem is
   "I wrote a class to write the .properties file it is working fine when i run 
   through normal application.But the problem is when i am using this in jsp means
   i have create object to this class and  used it in my jsp but Iam unble to modify/write
   the .properties file and Iam not getting any errors".

what is the problem please explain and give if any solution to implement/write
   .properties file from jsp.

Regards,
   Venkatesh Gurram.

Comment: Try posting the JSP code that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific reason that a JSP cannot write a properties file.  If it is not working and there are no apparent errors, then I suspect:

- the properties file is really being written, but not in the directory you are expecting it to be written,
- you have configured your logging to suppress error messages, or
- you are looking for errors in the wrong place.

IMO, the first is the most likely, especially if you are providing a relative pathname for the properties file.  (If you instantiate a FileOutputStream using a relative pathname, it will be resolved relative to the web server process's "current directory" ... which may not be where you think it is.)

Answer (score 0):

How did you define where you write your file ? Absolute or relative path ?

May be when you test your class you can write but when you test your jsp the location use the server location ?

Display the path in your jsp to check where it writes.